# Save value of codemirror editor in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, codemirror

I've recently started an in-browser text editor project that utilizes Codemirror. Basically I have three Codemirror editors set up; one for HTML, one for CSS, and one for Javascript. They all output to a result iframe. It's a pretty bare bones editor that doesn't incorporate a login system like Codepen or JSFiddle. However, I would like users to be able to save their code typed in each editor in localStorage. This way, one could use the editor, close the tab, and continue editing the same project once they reopened the website. The save feature would be triggered by a save button. Currently, I have a setup that resembles this:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="html-code" placeholder="Type your HTML here..."></textarea>
<textarea id="css-code" placeholder="Type your CSS here..."></textarea>
<textarea id="js-code" placeholder="Type your Javascript here..."></textarea>

<button id="save">Save</button>
```

**In script tag:**

```
var html = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("html-code"), {
    mode: 'htmlmixed',
    lineNumbers: true,
});

var css = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("css-code"), {
    mode: 'text/css',
    lineNumbers: true,
});

var js = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("js-code"), {
    mode: 'text/javascript',
    lineNumbers: true,
});
```

Is there a simple localStorage function that I could trigger from a button click? I've tried setting the values of the textareas as localStorage items, but something about my syntax never seems to work. If anybody has any experience with this, all help is appreciated! JQuery would be preferred. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp ? If so what about it didnt work?

Comment: @sbondo1234 Yes. I tried localStorage.setItem("currentText", html.getValue()), and set it to be the value of the editor on page load, for each language. I admit I'm not very versed in web storage, however.

Comment: What happens when storing? Have you tried to console.log the localStorage item and see what is being stored?

Comment: Actually, the console shows that the current value of the editor is in fact being stored. I suppose the problem would be how I'm putting the item back into the editor on page load.

Comment: Could be, how are you putting it back into the editor? This looks like a good resource: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local

Comment: I've tried a few methods, first document.getElementById('html-code').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('currentText'), then $('#html-code').html(localStorage.getItem('currentText')). Neither of them seem to work. I'm wondering if it's a problem with the placeholders.

Comment: When using either of these, have you checked the console with F12 to see if there are any errors? If there are any errors posting them here would be great.